# Can I make a 3D Unity Android social media game without integrating with Eclipse or another IDE?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

Have not seen this one asked before and I am a pretty big novice to mobile game development. The team I work with would prefer to avoid Eclipse if at all possible, but our app requires advanced features such as integration with Facebook and Youtube and making calls to remote database servers. Can Unity support this without need for Eclipse or Netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of anything that would stop you from building your application without Eclipse or Netbeans, android sdk comes with a full set of tools for building applications, you'll just have to take care of building scripts yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has unity plugin you can download it from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity). I have used it once it's simple really. I don't have any idea about youtube but form making calls to server you can use Unity's [WWW class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html).